# function based index

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

```
select
<here I have functions like to_char, nvl, rtrim, ltrim, sum, decode>
from
table1
table2
where
joining conditions 1
joining conditions 2
group by
<here I have functions like to_char, nvl, rtrim, ltrim, sum, decode>
```

I got this query from production and looking at it need to provide few solutions to tune, I m thinking of using function based inbex for group by columns. I think select columns need not be index. I will get enviornment in couple of days but before that I need to come up with different apporaches. What all things I need to check if function by index is useful? Also, apart from explain plan which other documents I need to ask from DBAs?

I m adding actual sql here, I have asked for explain plan, which I will get in sometime :-

```
SELECT
  D_E_TRADE.DATE_VALUE,
  to_char(D_E_TRADE.DATE_VALUE,'Mon-yyyy'),
  NVL(P_DIM.P_NAME,' '),
  rtrim(ltrim(P_DIM.C_CTRY)),
  D_E_TRADE.YEAR,
  L_E_DIM.L_CODE,
  NVL(D_DIM.DESCR,' '),
  ( decode(D_DIM.DEPT_ID,'-1',' ',D_DIM.DEPT_ID) ),
  sum(A_CGE.TOTAL_CALC_NET_FEES),
  L_E_DIM.L_NAME,
  decode(A_CGE.E_M_CENTER,-9,0,A_CGE.E_M_CENTER),
  NVL(F_DIM.S_DESC,'-1'),
  sum(A_CGE.C_TOTAL_SHARES)
FROM
  DATE_D  D_E_TRADE,
  P_DIM,
  L_E_DIM,
  D_DIM,
  A_CGE,
  F_DIM
WHERE
  ( D_E_TRADE.DATE_KEY=A_CGE.T_KEY  )
  AND  ( P_DIM.PARTY_KEY=A_CGE.E_P_KEY  )
  AND  ( F_DIM.F_T_KEY=A_CGE.F_T_KEY  )
  AND  ( L_E_DIM.L_E_KEY=A_CGE.L_E_KEY  )
  AND  ( D_DIM.DEPT_KEY=A_CGE.DEPT_KEY  )
  AND  
  (
   rtrim(ltrim(P_DIM.C_CTRY))  =  'AC'
   AND
   ( A_CGE.T_KEY >= (SELECT   DATE_D_PROMPTS.DATE_KEY FROM   DATE_D  DATE_D_PROMPTS WHERE (  DATE_D_PROMPTS.DATE_VALUE = '01-01-2012 00:00:00'  ) )
 AND
 A_CGE.T_KEY <= (SELECT  DATE_D_PROMPTS.DATE_KEY FROM   DATE_D  DATE_D_PROMPTS WHERE  (  DATE_D_PROMPTS.DATE_VALUE = '31-08-2012 00:00:00'  ))
  AND
 A_CGE.TRANS_REGION_KEY IN (SELECT REGION_KEY FROM REGION_DIM WHERE REGION_DIM.REGION_NAME IN ('Americas') )                                                                                                       )
   AND
   ( A_CGE.T_KEY >= (SELECT   DATE_D_PROMPTS.DATE_KEY FROM   DATE_D  DATE_D_PROMPTS WHERE (  DATE_D_PROMPTS.DATE_VALUE = '01-01-2012 00:00:00'  ) )
 AND
 A_CGE.T_KEY <= (SELECT  DATE_D_PROMPTS.DATE_KEY FROM   DATE_D  DATE_D_PROMPTS WHERE  (  DATE_D_PROMPTS.DATE_VALUE = '31-08-2012 00:00:00'  ))
  AND
 A_CGE.TRANS_REGION_KEY IN (SELECT REGION_KEY FROM REGION_DIM WHERE REGION_DIM.REGION_NAME IN ('Americas') )                                                                                                       )
   AND
   ( 'All Fees' IN ('2 - E','3 - P','4 - F','5 - C,')     OR                                                                                                                                        A_CGE.F_T_KEY IN (SELECT F_T_KEY FROM F_DIM WHERE (F_DIM.s_id ) || ' - ' || ( F_DIM.CHARGE_LVL1_NAME ) IN ('2 - E','3 - P','4 - F','5 - C'))  )
  )
GROUP BY
  D_E_TRADE.DATE_VALUE, 
  to_char(D_E_TRADE.DATE_VALUE,'Mon-yyyy'), 
  NVL(P_DIM.P_NAME,' '), 
  rtrim(ltrim(P_DIM.C_CTRY)), 
  D_E_TRADE.YEAR, 
  L_E_DIM.L_CODE, 
  NVL(D_DIM.DESCR,' '), 
  ( decode(D_DIM.DEPT_ID,'-1',' ',D_DIM.DEPT_ID) ), 
  L_E_DIM.L_NAME, 
  decode(A_CGE.E_M_CENTER,-9,0,A_CGE.E_M_CENTER), 
  NVL(F_DIM.S_DESC,'-1')
```

Comment: no, adding a FBI for the group by isn't the place to start, you need to look at the filtering (where clause) and see what you can do there (indexing, changing the query etc). you'd need to provide an SQL to look at/explain plans etc as this is too broad at the moment.

Comment: I have added actual sql for more clarification.

Comment: I'm waiting for the explain plan.

Answer (score 1):

Generaly, indexes help you on fast retrieval of data when you have filtering conditions wich may use the indexes.

(Another case whold be when you retrieve only column that are in the index, so the engine does not need to read anything from table)

In your case, you may need indexes on filtering/join conditions in the following part:

```
joining conditions 1
joining conditions 2
```

But keep in mind. If the you get more than 15%-20% of rows of a table, is better to read from table, not to use the index. That is, the index may not be used.

Comment: What all documents I need to ask and which I need for tunning, apart from explain plan where the query is running.

Comment: Also in where clause, if we put filerting condition before joining, will that make any difference?

Comment: tough question. I don't know. Maybe [oracle sql tunning docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/sql_1016.htm) or [another tips on the web, searching oracle sql tuning](http://www.orafaq.com/tuningguide/)

Comment: the order in where clause does not have any importance.

Comment: Added actual sql for further clarification